# Send Jenkins container's logs to syslog

Tags: docker, logging

Using the Jenkins TLS docker image, how do I write the logs to the docker host machine? The only way I've been able to get it to work is to run the container interactively and redirect the output but that seems bad in so many ways. Below is how it currently runs:

```
docker run \
--init -d \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 50000:50000 \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
-v /var/log/jenkins:/var/log/jenkins \
my.repo/jenkins:latest
```

(so the "fix" was to add ">> /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log 2>&1" to the end, seems like a terrible idea)

I was trying to use the syslog driver but it does not seem to work - I have UDP 514 open and I was able to write a message to it using logger but nothing seems to show up for the container.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth you can do this using the log-driver. In my case I am running in AWS so adding the following to your container's run command works:

```
docker run -it --log-driver awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=jenkins --log-opt awslogs-stream-prefix=master
```

As long as the infrastructure running the container has appropriate IAM rights you should see the logs show up in CloudWatch.